# Div not showing from jquery click using .show

Tags: jquery, html

I have `div` within another `div`. I would like to show the div when a radio button is selected, in particular the "yes" radio button.

I tried adding e.preventDefault, but makes the radio button stop working.

JQuery:

```
<script>
$("#areaDiv input:radio").click(function () {

            var selectedVal = $("#areaDiv input:radio:checked").val();
            //alert(selectedVal);
            if (selectedVal == true) {
                $("#areaDetail").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#areaDetail").hide();
            }
        })
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="areaDiv" class="inputGroup spacer">
                            <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.PreHealth)</strong>
                            <label class="unselectable labelledCheckbox">
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.PreHealth, false)
                                No
                            </label>
                            <label class="unselectable labelledCheckbox">
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.PreHealth, true)
                                Yes
                            </label>
                            <div id="areaDetail" hidden>
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.PreHealthArea)
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I want the the texbox to show from the `div` with `id=areaDetail`, when the yes radio box is selected.

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML instead of whatever language that is? Also, have you checked the browser's console for errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because the true value you are retrieving is a string and not a boolean. Try this:

```
        if (selectedVal == "true") {
            $("#areaDetail").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#areaDetail").hide();
        }
```

Comment: Yeah turns out it needed to be string value of "True", capital T, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just attach `change` event handler for the `input[type="radio"]` elements and then check if the `Yes` (give that one an `ID`) `button` is checked then show the `div` otherwise hide it.

```js
const rBtns = $('input[type=radio]'),
  yes = $('#yes'),
  detail = $('#areaDetail');

rBtns.on('change', () => yes.is(':checked') ? detail.show() : detail.hide());
```

```html
<!-- for demo purposes removed the expression begining with "@" -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="areaDiv" class="inputGroup spacer">
  <label class="unselectable labelledCheckbox">
        No
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="no">
    </label>
  <label class="unselectable labelledCheckbox">
        Yes
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="yes">
    </label>
  <div id="areaDetail" hidden>
    some content that appears when Yes radio button is checked.
  </div>
</div>
```